# What sort of Rice do Chinese Restaurants use

Tags: rice, chinese-cuisine

What sort of Rice do Chinese Restaurants use?
I use good quality Thai Rice at home in my rice cooker, I have tried all sorts of brands of rice and I have tried mixing different rice together, but, I have never been able to achieve the same taste of rice that I have had in Chinese Restaurants. Any advice?

Comment: Chinese restaurants where? China? US? EU?

Comment: Much though I love the linked question - it does pose the same issue as this one. The question is about takeaway food (without mentioning the territory it's taken away from), yet the answers are all about real Chinese cooking.

Comment: Ok, good point.  That said, without a location we can't really get more specific.  And honestly, I'm pretty sure the answers to the other question cover this one, particularly the 3-page-long answer.